# How to typecast a double to a string inside a enum structure in C#

Tags: c#, string, enums, casting

None of these work :

```
 public enum OsVersioniOS : int
 { 
    '8.0' = 1 << 0,
    "8.1" = 1 << 1,
    string(8.2) = 1 << 2,
 }
```

I want 8.0 [which is type of iOS operating system] to be seen as string inside the enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done, enums must have valid idetifiers according to the subsection Identifiers (subsection 2.4.2 in the [C# 5.0 version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)) of the C# Language Specification, the best you can do is use a [`DisplayAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) which may or may not get picked up automatically depending on the framework you are using to display information to the user.

```
public enum OsVersioniOS : int
{ 
    [Display(ShortName="8.0")]
    v8_0 = 1 << 0,
    [Display(ShortName="8.1")]
    v8_1 = 1 << 1,
    [Display(ShortName="8.2")]
    v8_2 = 1 << 2,
}
```

Here is a helper extension method that can turn the enum in to it's string description if you are not using a framework that will automatically pull the ShortName.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the text from the <see cref="DisplayAttribute"/> ShortName associated with the enum member.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The enum value to check.</param>
/// <returns>The value of the Display - ShortName attribute or null if not available.</returns>
public static string GetShortName(this Enum enumValue)
{
    return enumValue.GetType()
                    .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                    .First()
                    .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
                    .GetShortName();
}
```

Comment: More precisely, the `enum` members must have names that are valid ___identifiers___ according to the subsection _Identifiers_ (subsection 2.4.2 in the version I am having) of the C# Language Specification. In particular, the start character must be a letter or an underscore.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks, updated answer and provided ta link to the C# spec.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, the correct way is:

```
public enum OsVersioniOS
 { 
    [Description("8.1")]
    One,
    [Description("8.2")]
    Two
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Scott and Renato have both said, the proper way to achieve this is to use an attribute to decorate the enumeration with the information you want to display.

```
public enum OsVersioniOS : int
{ 
    [Display(Name="8.0")]
    Version_8_0 = 1 << 0,
    [Display(Name="8.1")]
    Version_8_1 = 1 << 1,
    [Display(Name="8.2")]
    Version_8_2 = 1 << 2,
    //etc.
}
```

Once you have those attributes defined, you can then retrieve your settings from the enumerations via reflection. For example:

```
{
     OsVersioniOS enumMember = GetEnumThatYouNeedNameOf();
     var type = typeof(OsVersioniOS);
     var memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumMember.ToString());
     var attribute = (DisplayAttribute)memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute),false)
     var value = attribute.Name;
     return value;
}
```

I would suggest wrapping that in an extension method or static helper method if you are going to be using it a lot. If you need more values, you can create your own attribute instead of using Display or Description.